# Python Dictionary Function

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, dictionary

The code is this and the output is two but I can't figure out why that is the output.

```
def dictTest(d, aVal):
    for k in d:
        if d[k] == aVal:
            return k
    return None

lengths = {'one':3, 0:1, 'two':3}
print(dictTest(lengths, 3))
```

Comment: What exactly are you having difficulty understanding? Go through the code line by line and try and see what each bit does.

Comment: Dictionaries do not hold order. Keep running the code over and over again, eventually you will get one, then you will get two, then you will get one again. Because dictionaries do not preserve order. This is why: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15479928/why-is-the-order-in-dictionaries-and-sets-arbitrary

Comment: When I go line by line, I see: if index 0 in the dictionary == 3 then return k

Comment: This is a review question for an exam and in the idle it outputs two but on the exam a possible answer is one but not two

Comment: I know that dictionaries don't hold order but in the exam situation, a possible answer choice is one, would it be wrong if I selected that as a choice

Comment: @MattSchumacher If you know dictionaries don't hold order, then you should know that based on the logic you wrote and the data you are providing, you will never be guaranteed to get ONLY `one` and never be guaranteed to get ONLY `two`. But you are guaranteed to get `one` OR `two`

Comment: I understand now. so it will only return one thing. and in the exam selecting one would be correct. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries have no sense of ordering, so if you're checking if a value is a particular number, there's no guarantee you'll get the key that you're expecting to find if you have duplicate values.

If you want to Guarantee that a dictionary will be ordered, you can use collections.OrderedDict: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict

Comment: You're very welcome!

Answer (score 0):

While inserting the elements into the dictionary, they are not ordered. If you run your code multiple times, it would give you a varied result of 'one' and 'two'.

If your intention was to get all the key's for that value, you can store them in a list and return them.